# Can I schedule startup and shutdown with different settings for weekdays and weekends?

Tags: sleep-wake, startup, macos

Everyday, I usually start my Mac Mini at 16:00 and shutdown it at 2:00 using the Energy Saver schedule settings.

I would like to be able to set a different behavior on the Weekends starting Mac Mini at 9:00 for example. Do you know any way to achieve that (third party software, cron job, superuser trick)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need 3rd party software. The OS X utility **pmset** allows you to schedule sleep/wake taking day of week into effect. I haven't tested it, but it appears you cannot schedule multiple repeating events on different times. You'll need to use cron to complete this task.

from **man pmset**

```
Schedules the system to automatically wake from sleep on 
July 4, 2009, at 8PM.

pmset schedule wake "07/04/09 20:00:00"

Schedules a repeating shutdown to occur each day, Tuesday through 
Saturday, at 11AM.

pmset repeat shutdown TWRFS 11:00:00
```

Comment: I fiddled with it and it can't be done even using pmset

Comment: I think if you fiddle differently it can be done. You'll want to use pmset with StartupItems so that each time it starts it is correctly set for the next shutdown, and a new StartupItem is written for the next reboot.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [DssW Power Manager](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/). With Power Manager, you can create multiple separate start up and shut down times for weekdays and weekends.

Power Manager [goes far beyond](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/cookbook/) the capabilities of pmset. [How to schedule your Mac to shut down](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xguaEyN-iU0) (screen recording on YouTube).

[image: Power Manager for Mac OS X]

Disclaimer: I work for DssW.

Comment: Wow - that's a nice looking tool. Thank you for answering and disclosing your ties to the product.

Answer (score 0):

For the shutdown part I can suggest [Mac Shutdown X](http://www.pomola.com/products_macshutdown/macshutdown.html) (shareware 20$), It is customizable using an easy to use setting setup panel (no coding or editing of script required).

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me:

```
sudo pmset repeat shutdown MTWRF 16:00:00
```

For shutting down every weekday. I bet `amset` instead of `pmset` would work for waking them up.

Comment: pm stands for power management, not am/pm. The OP asks for multiple events, so this is only a partial solution.