# How do I schedule Mac OS X Leopard to wake up multiple times in one day?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, leopard

The "Energy Saver" panel in System Preferences allows the user to schedule wake ups. The only problem is is that the most frequent it allows for this to happen is ONCE per day. Is there any way or any tool or any software that can make it wake up at any custom interval? I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.8.

Comment: What would be the usage scenario here?  What do you do to need it to wake multiple times?

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/can-i-schedule-startup-and-shutdown-with-different-settings-for-weekdays-and-wee and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111980/how-do-i-schedule-mac-os-x-leopard-to-wake-up-multiple-times-in-one-day

Comment: In reply to deiga: I need to be able to access it remotely through the day, but I don't wish to leave my screen on all the time, so it's a compromise where I can connect to it between given intervals.

Answer (score 0):

This app seems to be the solution to your problem. http://www.ibeezz.com/en/

Haven't tested it myself though.

Answer (score 0):

This article,  [How to Power On Your Mac at a Specific Date and Time](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2010/11/02/how-to-power-on-your-mac-at-a-specific-date-and-time/), shows how to schedule your Mac to power on using Energy Saver, `pmset`, and Power Manager.

The most capable method is with [Power Manager](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/standard); it can schedule the multiple power on and wake up events you need using the Graphical User Interface (GUI).

Power Manager supports Mac OS X 10.6 and later, but the [previous version](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/legacy/) is still available and supports Mac OS X 10.4 - 10.7 for PPC and Intel.

*Disclosure: I work for the company who makes Power Manager.*

[image: Power Manager]

Comment: I'm not competent with the command line, so I don't know how well I'd be able to use `pmset` without making a mistake and Power Manager isn't available for Mac OS X **Leopard**.

Comment: @Melab Power Manager 3 is still available and it works with Mac OS X 10.5, aka Leopard. The previous version link in the answer includes a download.