# Sleep/wake Mac mini by pressing power button

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini, power, power-management

I have a Mac mini that is on my network but not connected to any displays or input devices. It's running El Capitan.

I want to be able to put the Mac to sleep and awake it as easily as possible (i.e. not using VNC). My main machine is Windows, so ideally I just want to press the power button to toggle the Mac between sleeping and awake.

Is this possible? From what I've read, it seems like this used to be possible but now it isn't? Are there any workarounds that would enable this?

Comment: Does this do what you need?  `defaults write com.apple.loginwindow PowerButtonSleepsSystem -bool yes`

Comment: @Allan: no, that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: To put your mac to sleep, try tapping the power button once. That should do it. The power button needs to be held down to turn it off that way.

Comment: @NoahL as per my question, that's the first thing I tried.

Comment: Oops sorry! @KentBoogaart I missed that.

Comment: If your need to wake and sleep the Mac is regular, it is possible to schedule this on macOS; see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2655/can-i-schedule-startup-and-shutdown-with-different-settings-for-weekdays-and-wee

Comment: Thanks, but already seen that @GrahamMiln. Unfortunately, my requirements are not regular.

Answer (score 4):

You can no longer just tap the Power Button on a Mac to put it to Sleep. On any Mac running Mavericks or newer the Power Button should function as follows:

```
Power Button:
1~2 second hold = Sleep
3~5 second hold = Options Dialog
8~12 second hold = Force Shut Down
```

Alternatively, if you have a keyboard hooked into the Mac you should be able to hit:
 **`Control+Shift+(Power Button on the Mac or Media Eject on Mac keyboard)`** to put your Mac to sleep.

To wake it up just hit the **`Power Button`**, or enable Wake On Network if you want to remotely wake the system.

**EDIT:**
If you need to sleep your system across the network (with no physical access), and have access to the command line you can do one of the following.

1. Using AppleScript from the command line.
   `osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep'`
2. From any command line connection you can also try.
   `pmset sleep now`

**ADDITION:**
Network traffic (active network connection allowing file sharing for example) can stop the standard Sleep action on a Mac when hitting the power button. You need to make sure that there are no active network connections, especially if you have "Wake on Network" enabled.

On some system you will need to make sure that the `System Preferences... -> Energy Saver` settings are set properly to allow the power button to sleep the system. Depending on the Mac hardware you are running on (Mac Mini vs MacBook) some settings will or won't be on the Energy Saver panel.

[image: Mac Mini Energy Saver Screen]

For a complete list of Energy Saving info, and to learn more about [Apple Power Setting for El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21704) head over to Apple's website.

Comment: :sob: I'm not on the Mac. Please read the question again.

Comment: Sorry, your question makes it sound like you have physical access to the system even though it's on the network.

Comment: I do have physical access, but there's no keyboard attached. Thus I'd have to VNC just to try what you suggest. I need this to be quick and easy because the Mac will be up and down several times on a daily basis.

Comment: I added a minor clarification to my question. Can you please delete your answer?

Comment: Sorry I had added a clarification, but just saw your change to the question.

Comment: my main machine is Windows :) More clarification added

Comment: You do know you can't just tap the power button anymore, you must hold if for the proper time interval. I have added this information to the top of my answer.

Comment: Thanks @kenjikato. I did not know that. Not only is that terrible (how do you not accidentally hold for too long unless you've got a drummer's sense of time?) but it also does not seem to do anything.

Comment: When running a Mac Mini headless it's general assumed that you will be doing this stuff over the network. But since you want a physical power press without keyboard or monitor, it's going to be all about the timing. Pressing power for 1~2 second should do the trick. You will know if you got it because the power light should go out, then cycle up and down. My Dell system does the same thing under Windows 7.

Comment: I understand what _should_ be happening, but it's _not_ happening. And why would it be assumed that this stuff be done over the network? A quick press of the power switch seems the most logical means of putting the device to sleep. Indeed, that apparently _was_ the behavior in the past.

Comment: If there's an active network connection to the system (file sharing, remote dev, web services with active connection), then it won't go to sleep when holding the power button for a second or two. You need to make sure that there are not network connections for the pure power button sleep to work. There are also some apps that will stop this from happening, and can override the sleep behavior. That's just the way it is with what Apple has done with the newer systems.

Comment: Just tried physically disconnecting the Ethernet cable, then holding power button for 1.5s. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you at this point as I've just tried all these thing on a Mac Mini running El Cap. You could try rebooting the system (with a keyboard connected) and holding down on Option+Command+P+R to reset the PRAM. This is an old trick, but will sometimes clear issues like this. You also might have a background app running on the system that's stopping the sleep action.

Comment: One last thing, you can go over to the Apple Website and check the Power Saver Settings for yourself at this address: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21704